# Where to get the microservice registration time in consul

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-consul

My microservice called user-service and registration in consul.But in consul panel no time show.I would like to get what time the service is registered.Is there any way to achieve?

Now the panel show below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consul does not record when a service was registered into the catalog.

You could implement this yourself by recording the registration time in a metadata tag on when registering the service. See Consul's [Service Registration - Adding Meta Data](https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/services#adding-meta-data) docs for more info.